# Query columns containing special characters or starting with digits with SQL statement in DolphinDB

Tags: sql, pivot, stack, pivot-table, dolphindb

Server version: `2.00.8 2022.09.28`

I obtain a table re with `pivot by` in DolphinDB and the generated column names contain special characters.

```
date = take(2021.08.01  2021.08.02 2021.08.03, 12)
sym = take(["IBM N", "_MSFTN", "3_GOOGS", ""], 12).sort()
value = 1..12
t=table(date, sym, value)
re = select value from t pivot by date, sym
```

[image]

When I query table re with a `select` statement,

```
select 3_GOOGS  from re
```

An error message “Can't recognize token 3_GOOGS“ is raised. How can I fix the query?

Comment: In Access would use `[]` delimiters, other platforms use apostrophes. Dolphindb documentation does not indicate there is a way to force acceptance of non-conforming field names: https://www.dolphindb.com/help/DataTypesandStructures/DataForms/Table.html

Answer (score 1):

When column names containing special characters or starting with digits are used in SQL statements, they should be enclosed in double quotes and use an underscore as an identifier before it in DolphinDB. For example: _”IBM.N”, _”000001.SH”. So your query can be modified as:

```
select _"3_GOOGS" from re
```